# Insertar datos en dos tablas a la vez en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente método para insertar datos en una tabla de SQL SERVER, el problema ocurre cuando quiero insertar en la tabla `ProdAnalisis` y `ProdMuestreo` al mismo tiempo, me marca error:

> "Store-generated keys are only supported for identity columns. Key
>   column 'Cod_Prod' has type 'SqlServer.varchar', which is not a valid
>   type for an identity column."

La clave primaria de mi tabla `ProdMuestreo` es `Cod_Empresa,Cod_Prod,Cod_Campo` (las 3 juntas porque así las necesito) y la clave primaria de `ProdAnalisis` es `Id`.

Lo que necesito es que al guardar un registro en `ProdAnalisis` se guarde el `Id` (de este mismo) en la tabla `ProdMuestreo` en el campo `Id_Analisis`.
Espero darme a entender.
Gracias.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Analisis(ProdAnalisis model)
 {
  try
  {
  ProdAnalisis.Cod_Prod = model.Cod_Prod;
  ProdAnalisis.Cod_Campo = model.Cod_Campo;
  ProdAnalisis.Sector = model.Sector;
  ProdAnalisis.IdAgen = (short)Session["IdAgen"];
  ProdAnalisis.Cultivo = model.Cultivo;
  ProdAnalisis.Variedad = model.Variedad;
  ProdAnalisis.IdRegion = model.IdRegion;
  ProdAnalisis.Fecha_envio = DateTime.Now;
  ProdAnalisis.Fecha_entrega = DateTime.Now;
  ProdAnalisis.Status = model.Status;
  ProdAnalisis.Num_analisis = model.Num_analisis;
  ProdAnalisis.Laboratorio = model.Laboratorio;
  ProdAnalisis.Temporada = "1920";
  ProdAnalisis.Comentarios = model.Comentarios;
  ProdAnalisis.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
  ProdAnalisis.Id_Muestreo = model.Id;

  ProdMuestreo.Id_Analisis = ProdAnalisis.Id;

    bd.ProdMuestreo.Add(ProdMuestreo);  
    bd.ProdAnalisis.Add(ProdAnalisis);                    
    bd.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception e) 
     { e.ToString(); }
 }
```

Mis modelos

```
    public partial class ProdAnalisis
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Cod_Prod { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Cod_Campo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Sector { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> IdAgen { get; set; }
        public string Cultivo { get; set; }
        public string Variedad { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> IdRegion { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_envio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_entrega { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Num_analisis { get; set; }
        public string Laboratorio { get; set; }
        public string Temporada { get; set; }
        public string Comentarios { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Id_Muestreo { get; set; }


        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProdMuestreo> ProdMuestreo { get; set; }

    }


    public partial class ProdMuestreo
    {        
        public Nullable<int> Id_Analisis { get; set; }
        public short Cod_Empresa { get; set; }
        public string Cod_Prod { get; set; }
        public short Cod_Campo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_solicitud { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_ejecucion { get; set; }
        public string Ubicacion { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> IdAgen { get; set; }
        public string Liberacion { get; set; }
        public string Cultivo { get; set; }
        public string Variedad { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Tarjeta { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Calidad_fruta { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha_calidad { get; set; }    
        public virtual ProdAnalisis ProdAnalisis{ get; set; }      
    }
```

DB.Context

```html
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class SEntities : DbContext
    {
        public SEntities()
            : base("name=SEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
            
        public virtual DbSet<ProdAnalisis> ProdAnalisis { get; set; }       
        public virtual DbSet<ProdMuestreo> ProdMuestreo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de los registros que tengo y como quiero que se guarden los datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, indica por favor tu clase `DbContext` de Entity Framework.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta ya lo agregue, gracias

Comment: Lo que buscas es registrar y luego de haber registrado, actualizar los IDs correspondientes para que la relación de las tablas se mantenga en buen estado, ¿cierto?

Comment: Si eso necesito @fredyfx

Comment: Entonces, para confirmar, en la imagen que muestras, en el id 1 (fila número 2), el campo que dice Id_Analisis_Residuo que tiene NULL ¿debería estar el Id 4 de la segunda tabla? Por otro lado, ¿Dónde defines la propiedad Id_Analisis_Residuo ?

Comment: si, exactamente asi @fredyfx

Comment: Ya te capté la idea, una pregunta más: ¿Dónde defines la propiedad Id_Analisis_Residuo?

Comment: En ProdMuestreo es Id_Analisis , disculpa fue error de dedo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100259/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-huntzberger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El título no es el adecuado para el escenario, pensé que era un registro en cascada y según lo que encontré en tu código, no es una cascada como tal, en fin, creo que esto es lo que estás buscando en tu controlador "Analisis":

```
 ProdAnalisis.Cod_Prod = model.Cod_Prod;
 ProdAnalisis.Cod_Campo = model.Cod_Campo;
 ProdAnalisis.Sector = model.Sector;
 ProdAnalisis.IdAgen = (short) Session["IdAgen"];
 ProdAnalisis.Cultivo = model.Cultivo;
 ProdAnalisis.Variedad = model.Variedad;
 ProdAnalisis.IdRegion = model.IdRegion;
 ProdAnalisis.Fecha_envio = DateTime.Now;
 ProdAnalisis.Fecha_entrega = DateTime.Now;
 ProdAnalisis.Status = model.Status;
 ProdAnalisis.Num_analisis = model.Num_analisis;
 ProdAnalisis.Laboratorio = model.Laboratorio;
 ProdAnalisis.Temporada = "1920";
 ProdAnalisis.Comentarios = model.Comentarios;
 ProdAnalisis.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
 ProdAnalisis.Id_Muestreo = model.Id;

 //ProdMuestreo.Id_Analisis = ProdAnalisis.Id; //Aqui es null porque NO se tiene

 bd.ProdMuestreo.Add(ProdMuestreo);
 bd.ProdAnalisis.Add(ProdAnalisis);
 bd.SaveChanges();

 //Ahora que ya se guardó en la BD, tenemos los siguientes valores:
 //Esta data viene por cortesía de Entity Framework
 var IdDelRegistroInsertadoEnProdMuestreo = ProdMuestreo.Id;
 var IdDelRegistroInsertadoEnProdAnalisis = ProdAnalisis.Id;

 //Ahora, un select para encontrar el prodMuestreo insertado:
 var prodMuestreoObj = bd.ProdMuestreo.First(x => x.Id == IdDelRegistroInsertadoEnProdMuestreo);
 prodMuestreoObj.Id_Analisis = IdDelRegistroInsertadoEnProdAnalisis;     
 //Opción 1: 
 bd.SaveChanges(); //Esto hace seguimiento a todas las entidades que han tenido un cambio

 //Opción 2:
 bd.ProdMuestreo.Update(prodMuestreoObj); //Definimos de manera más exacta lo que se tiene que cambiar.
 bd.SaveChanges();
```

Finalmente lecturas recomendadas:

- https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset/modifying-data
- https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Answer (score 0):

Una columna identidad (Identity) significa que el servidor de SQL va a incrementar de forma automática el valor cada vez que se inserte un nuevo registro. Por lo tanto debería ser un tipo numérico, y no un tipo texto.

Ejemplo:

```
Id (Autoincremental)           Campo1
--------------------------------------
1                              'Test1'
2                              'Test2'
3                                ...
4                                ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un trigger AFTER INSERT, directamente en la base de datos, a mi parecer es más optimo por que sólo tiene que preocuparte por insertar en la tabla maestra y SQL Server se encarga de insertar en la tabla Detalle.
Mira éste ejemplo que encontré en Internet en http://moleskinformatico.blogspot.com/2010/02/trigger-after-insert-update-sql-server.html:

Creo la Tabla Empleado

```
create table Empleado(
nombre varchar(20),
apellido varchar(20))
```

En esta se guardará automaticamente lo que se guardo en 
la Tabla Empleado

```
create table Empleado_Log(
nombre varchar(20),
apellido varchar(20),
direccion varchar(100),
edad int)
```

Creo Trigger, se ejecutará después de insertar o actualizar la 
tabla Empleado e insertará los neuvos datos insertados en Empleado
en la tabla Empleado_Log

```
Create trigger trg_Empleado_Log
on Empleado
after insert,update
as
BEGIN
    set nocount on;
    declare
    @nombre varchar(20),
    @apellido varchar(20)

    select @nombre = nombre,@apellido = apellido 
    from inserted

    declare
    @direccion varchar(100),
    @edad int

    set @direccion='Av 15, Santa Marina'
    set @edad = 22

    begin
        insert into Empleado_Log values(@nombre,@apellido,@direccion,@edad )
    end
END
```

Probando

```
insert into Empleado values('Pedro','Casas')
select * from Empleado
select * from Empleado_Log

update Empleado set nombre = 'Carlos'
select * from Empleado
select * from Empleado_Log
```